# How to separate GPU workoad on windows

Tags: gpu

I'd like to buy a multi GPU motherboard but wanted to separate the workloads separately on each GPU using windows

I know you can select a GPU for high performance in Windows 10 but that's not separating tasks/workloads

I.e. one GPU can work using one program and another GPU using another program without sharing workloads

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of explicit multi-GPU management is supported by DirectX 12.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/directx-12-multiadapter-lighting-up-dormant-silicon-and-making-it-work-for-you/

https://gpuopen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/GDC2017-Explicit-DirectX-12-Multi-GPU-Rendering.pdf

https://developer.nvidia.com/explicit-multi-gpu-programming-directx-12

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/multi-adapter-support-in-directx-12.html